# Do Python's slots contain methods?

Tags: python, slots

Let's say I do this class:

```
class Person:
   __slots__ = ["j"]

   def __init__(self):
       self.j = 1

   def hello(self):
       print("Hello")
```

Is the method *hello* in the slots?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work but maybe functions are stored another way. It is strange that you don't have to implicitly put em in the slots list.

Comment: Yes, they're stored on the *class* not the *instance* - they appear in neither `__slots__` nor `__dict__` on an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you're using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to control instance attributes, methods are stored on the *class*, not the *instance*:

```
>>> class Slots:

    __slots__ = ['attr']

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = None

    def method(self):
        pass


>>> class NoSlots:

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = None

    def method(self):
        pass


>>> 'method' in Slots.__dict__
True
>>> 'method' in NoSlots.__dict__
True
>>> 'method' in NoSlots().__dict__
False
```

Using `__slots__` actually makes all defined attributes [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) (see also [the how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)), which are also stored on the class:

```
>>> 'attr' in Slots.__dict__
True
>>> type(Slots.attr)
<class 'member_descriptor'>
```